# Reading a file with multiple section headers in Apache Spark with variable section content

Tags: java, scala, csv, apache-spark

Is it possible to use Spark APIs to read a **large** CSV file containing multiple sections having different headers? The structure of the file is as follows

```
BatchCode#1
Name,Surname,Address
AA1,BBB,CCC
AA2,BBB,CCC
AA3,BBB,CCC

BatchCode#2
Name,Surname,Address,Phone
XY1,BBB,CCC,DDD
XY2,BBB,CCC,DDD
XY3,BBB,CCC,DDD
```

While reading the records, we need to be careful with the headers as well as the file formats could be different between the sections. The BatchCode information needs to be extracted from the header and should be a part of every record within that section - for example, Data at line 1 should be parsed as:

```
Name: AAA1
Surname: BBB
Address:CCC
BatchCode:1
```

The following options come to my mind but I am not completely sure if it could create significant problems:

1. Reading the file using wholeTextFile. This will use a single thread to read the file but it would load the entire file in memory and could cause memory issues with large files.
2. Forcing Spark to read the file in a single thread using coalesce(1) on sc.textFile. I am not sure if the order is always guaranteed. Once we get the file as RDD, we will cache the header rows while reading the file and merge them with their corresponding data records.

Even if the above approaches work, would they be efficient? What would be the most efficient way?

Comment: coalesce() won't help in reading a file, only writing to a file. is `wholeTextFile` really a problem for you? how big is your dataset? i think your best solution will be to pre-process the file into multiple files, each with its own csv schema (unless this creates a huge amount of small files, in which case you're better of using a single streaming file parser)

Comment: See my answer. I can share some sample code.

Comment: wholeTextFiles wont work for us because we would have data set up to 20 GB as Input. Pre-process would be one option but I was trying to figure out if we could use Spark to do it inline. 

I am curious - what am I missing in the documentation for coalesce, it simply says -
Return a new RDD that is reduced into numPartitions partitions.

Comment: How about using binaryFiles option to read such files?

Comment: A new RDD is akin to writing.

Comment: I managed to get the sequence maintained using binaryFiles. Does anyone see a problem with this approach. I can share the code.

Comment: that is indeed an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program works for me:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> binaryFiles = sc.binaryFiles(file);

PortableRecordReader reader = new PortableRecordReader();
JavaPairRDD<String, Record> fileAndLines = binaryFiles.flatMapValues(reader);
```

Where PortableRecordReader opens a DataInputStream and converts it to an InputStreamReader and then uses a CSV parser to convert the lines to the intended output in Record object and also merges the header.

Comment: I suggest to improve this answer by providing the PortableRecordReader code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote Scala only programs for more complicated such use cases whereby sequentialness is guaranteed. It is too difficult otherwise. The files were processed via csvkit if emanating from xls or xlsx firstly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What is the approach of reading the files in scala. Pre-processor? Or are you using SparkContext.someMethod

Comment: I am using a SCALA only program - we looked at the stuff of checking if partition idex = 0 etc, but it is all too difficult. Also, the architects agreed that spinning up a SPARK job for smaller input is not really a goer. The question is, what is large in your case? Happy to share an example that was considered advanced, but you need to be a good programmer for this approach.

Comment: Can be parallelized

Comment: I would like to stick to Spark to reuse all the capabilities. It allows us to horizontally scale  and replicate between different data centers and regions using HDFS.

Comment: That is fine, but you use scala or pysprk with spark, or java. I successfully did otherwise. Success. The question is an open one and this is my answer.